# How I can make an query with mongoose from a function using a parameter?

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose

I try make a mongoose query using a function like this:

```
    /*
     * @param {function} Model - Mongoose Model
     * @param {String} searchText- Text that will be used to search for Regexp
     * @param {String} Key- key to search into a Model
     * @param {object} res - Response of node.js / express
    */

function _partialSearch (Model, searchText, key, res) {
  var search = new RegExp(searchText, "i");

  Model.find({ key : { $regex : search } })
  .exec(function (err, docs) {
    if(err) log(err);
    else {
      res.json(docs);
    }
  })
}
```

My problem is the query take a parameter key literal and search like this:

I need this:

```
_partialSearch(Products, 'banana', 'fruts', res)
```

I spect this:

```
   Products.find({ 'fruts' : 'banana})
```

But I get this:

```
Products.find({ key : 'banana})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the **[bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors)** to create the query object dynamically, so you could restructure your function as follows:

```
function _partialSearch (Model, searchText, key, res) {
    var search = new RegExp(searchText, "i"),
        query = {};
    query[key] = { $regex : search };

    Model.find(query)
         .exec(function (err, docs) {
            if(err) log(err);
            else {
                res.json(docs);
            }
         });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly use a variable as an object key like that, but assuming you're using Node.js 4.0 or above, you can use its ES6 support for [computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names) to do this by surrounding `key` in brackets:

```js
Model.find({ [key] : { $regex : search } })
```