# Creating query object for subdocuments

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I'm creating a modular query where you can include or omit the parameters dynamically.

This is the function I run at the end:

```
Schema.find(query,function (err, results) {})
```

For this purpose I created a query object:

```
var query = {}
```

And I add different properties to it. For instance:

```
query._id=12345
```

So the explicit for this case would look like this:

```
Schema.find({_id:12345}, function (err, results) {})
```

So far so good. 
My problem starts when I need to query a sub-document.

for instance when I need to create this query:

```
Schema.find({'children.sons.name':'michael'}, function...)
```

Because the only way I can create this object is by doing:

```
var query = {
    children: sons {
           name: 'michael'
                   }

            }
```

Which when I run through the 'find' function, is not interpreted as 'children.sons.name':'michael', but as the literal object.

What can I do?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. What's wrong with `query = {'children.sons.name': 'michael'}` ?

Comment: Nothing. I'm trying to replace the explicit string ''children.sons.name'' with a dynamically constructed variable.

Comment: Do you mean like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34578770/how-i-can-make-an-query-with-mongoose-from-a-function-using-a-parameter

Comment: I do! Thank you! I'll mark it as duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

It is because your data structure is invalid. You cannot define sub-document like that:

```
children: sons {
       name: 'michael'
    }
}
```

If there will be many `sons` under `children`, your document should be -

```
{
    children : {
        sons : [
            name: 'michael'
        ]
    }
}
```

And then, you can query as you want to.

```
Schema.find({'children.sons.name' : 'michael'}, function...)
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question. I don't want to explicitly query. I want to put a variable into the find function that contains all of my queries but I'm struggling to create it.